# MariaDB query from python code

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python

I'm writing a python script that connects to a MariaDB server (V 10.1.12) and saves to file the results of some queries.
However, when sending the following query:

```
sql =   'SELECT * FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Entry IN (SELECT MAX(Entry) ' \
        'FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Run in ({0}) ' \
        "AND WhenEntered<'{1}' GROUP BY Run)".format( runstr, quality_date )
```

followed by `cursor.execute( sql )`, I get the following error:

> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in
>   execute
>   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ') AND
>   WhenEntered<'2020-01-01' GROUP BY Run)' at line 1")

Could someone explain to me what the mistake is?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need your `runstr`

Comment: runstr is a string of numbers separated by comma: 'runstr = 60092,60093,60094'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the parenthesis around the nested select. It should be

```
SELECT * FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Entry IN (
        SELECT MAX(Entry)
        FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Run in ({0})
        AND WhenEntered<'{1}')
GROUP BY Run
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Entry IN (
        SELECT MAX(Entry)
        FROM Monitor_Run_Tracking WHERE Run in ({0})
        AND WhenEntered<'{1}'
        GROUP BY Run)
```

EDIT: For the other problem, you're grouping by a field that you're not selecting. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941763/group-by-a-field-not-in-select) for help.

Comment: Sorry, that mistake was a copy and paste from a one of my debugging iterations. It was originally closed properly. I edited the question appropriately now. Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer with a link that should resolve your problem.