# Can you group by a column you haven't selected in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am doing a past paper question. The database schema is:

- Customer(customerID,name,address, postcode),
- Orders(orderID, customerID REFERENCES Customer.customerID, orderDate,
  deliveryAddress)

I need to select the number of orders placed per customer along with the customer’s name, ordered by the most orders to the least.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(orderID) AS orders_placed, name
FROM Customer INNER JOIN
     Orders 
     ON Orders.customerID = Customer.customerID
GROUP BY Customer.customerID
ORDER BY orders_placed DESC;
```

My question is whether this query will work on all DBMS's? I am unsure because I am grouping by a column that I have not selected. If it does not work are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can group by a column that is not selected but you can't select by a column that is not grouped (at least not without an aggregate function).

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941763/group-by-a-field-not-in-select

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci . . . That is simply not true.

Comment: Note: the classical workaround (assuming name is functional dependent on (any) of the grouped_by variables) is `select MIN(c.name) as name, COUNT(*) as The_count FROM ... GROUP BY c.customerId;`

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can `group by` a column that you haven't selected.  That does not appear to be the gist of your question though.  You want to select a column that is not in the `group by`.  That is more interesting.

Assuming that `customerID` is unique, your syntax is correct ANSI syntax.  "Unique" is the simpler description of the relationship.  This is actually called a *functional dependency*.  Here is a pretty simple [blog](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/10/sql-group-by-and-functional-dependencies-a-very-useful-feature/) on the subject.

It has been part of the SQL standard for about 15 years, if I recall correctly.  However, the use of functional dependencies is optional and most databases do not support your syntax.

I believe the only databases that support it are Postgres, MySQL, and related databases.  Instead, you should include the name and all unaggregated expressions in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That a correct answer gets a downvote only shows the ignorance of the person who did it.

Comment: @Chris: the functional dependency is about the columns in the `group by`. If one is a primary key, then you can omit all others from the `group by` as it's clear that they won't change the grouping at all. In the question that would be the `name` column, e.g. Oracle would require you to add it to the `group by`

Comment: @Chris: it **is** relevant. If the "functional dependency" cannot be determined, the `name` column has to be added to the `group by` or you need to apply an aggregate on it (in the select list). But because there **is** a functional dependency there is no need to add it to the `group by`

Comment: The answer to "*can you group by a column you haven't selected*" is a clear YES independently of the database.